# oozie fails with Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: sqoop, oozie

I am getting below error while executing sqoop export command(in shell script) with oozie.

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"

sqoop export from cli(edge node) works fine.

I have added the ojdbc6.jar to below locations.
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/

(HDFS locations)
/user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop/ and 
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20161215195933/sqoop

i have also set oozie.use.system.libpath=true in my oozie job.properties file

Please guide me if i am missing any setting.
[log content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmGCX.png)

Thanks & Regards,
Sonali

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that you upload a file to a directory `/user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop` (it could looks like `/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_${timestamp}/sqoop` for Cloudera and HDP).
2. Check if ojdbc6.jar file is correct - check if it contains OracleDriver.class and make sure size of the file is ok. It could be error while downloading.
3. Check permissions to ojdbc6.jar file (eventually, you can try to give 755 permissions to this file). Check who is the owner of the file - it should be `oozie` by default.
4. Update Oozie sharelib by execute below command (run this command on the host where Oozie Server is located):

   ```
   sudo -u oozie oozie admin -oozie http://<Oozie_Server_Host>:11000/oozie -sharelibupdate
   ```
5. Verify sharelib for sqoop:

   ```
   sudo -u oozie oozie admin -oozie http://<Oozie_Server_Host>:11000/oozie -shareliblist sqoop*
   ```
6. You can always restart Oozie service. It should update sharelib.
7. Create a directory named `lib` next to your workflow.xml in HDFS and put jars in there. Oozie will automatically make those jars available to all actions in that workflow.

Cloudera users should check this [article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie-cdh-5/). Especially paragraph 'One Last Thing'.

Comment: @SonaliGhorpade I added more information to my first answer. I hope it will help you.

Comment: i have done all the above mentioned till steps 6 still same issue. Below is the file status  
-rwxr-xr-x   2 oozie hdfs    2739670 2017-10-12 03:21 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20161215195933/sqoop/ojdbc6.jar  
  
if i add the jar file in the workflow.xml, do i need to remove the below two lines from job.properties file?  
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/oozie/share/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true

Comment: No, you shoudn't. It is comma-separated list so you can try set there other locations. I added interesting article to my answer, you should check it. There is everything what you have to know about Oozie sherelib in Cloudera (but not only, HDP is really similiar).